# What is happening when require("http").Server() is evaluated with an Express app as its argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was reading the Socket.io Chat Demo here: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/
and I got confused when looking at their require statements.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Am I correct in thinking that `require("express")` produces an executable Express function (with all of the necessary functions and fields that go with that), and that `require("http").Server(app)` creates a http.Server object with all of its fields and functions.

If so, I am confused because Express creates a server when we call the .listen function so it seems redundant and backwards to pass an Express app to an http module server.

So, my question is, what is really happening here?

Comment: You're creating a webserver "instance" and passing it to sockec.io so it can use it for transport. `require` is just a function, if you return another function from the export, it can be called with arguments, and you can pass stuff to the middleware.

Comment: ExpressJS' [`app.listen()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.listen) is just for convenience for simple applications. It uses `http.Server(app)`, [or rather `http.createServer(app);`](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/4.10.6/lib/application.js#L558), itself.

Comment: so theoretically, I could just also write `io = require('socket.io')(http.createServer(app))` which should be the same then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The http server expects a function which has the following signature:

`function(req, res)`

`require('express')();` will create a function with that signature which handles all the magic that express makes available like routing, middleware, etc. Express *can* create it's own http server instance, but since you're also using socket.io (which expects access to the http server as well), you'll need a separate http instance.

Comment: In fact Express `.listen()` returns the server, so you *can* get access to it that way, but then you would be accepting connections before socketio could do its thing.

Comment: @Timothy: so does the variable `app` persist within both `http` and `io`?  It seems like it would have to for routing instructions to work.

Comment: express and socket.io override plug into the http server in different ways. For the most part, express just creates a middleware chain to pass the request / response through which will build up the response. Socket.io needs to plugin in front of that to ensure that its websocket upgrade requests aren't corrupted by any express middleware. Socket.io removes all the existing http handlers from the server, then only passes requests to express if it doesn't handle the request itself. See the implementation here: https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io/blob/master/lib/server.js#L342

Comment: @TimothyStrimple: Thanks for the explanation--I think I've got some research to do on JS itself, but your answer helped me to much better understand what was going on in the case.

Comment: The major confusion point for me: `app` *is* a function. 
 `app` has methods of its own, so it didn't look like a function, and everything I read suggested that `http.createServer(app)` needed a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = require('express')(); //infact, app is a requestListener function. 

var http = require('http').Server(app); // infact, function Server eqs http.createServer;

// infact,app.listen eqs http.listen
```

other code from nodejs and express model

we can see, require("express")() return app is a function.

```
//express/lib/express.js   https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/express.js

var proto = require('./application');

exports = module.exports = createApplication;

function createApplication() {
  var app = function(req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  };

  mixin(app, EventEmitter.prototype, false);
  mixin(app, proto, false);

  app.request = { __proto__: req, app: app };
  app.response = { __proto__: res, app: app };
  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

we can see, node.createServer eqs Server

```
//nodejs/lib/http.js  https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js

exports.createServer = function(requestListener) {
  return new Server(requestListener);
};
```

we can see, express app.listen eqs http.listen

```
//express/lib/application.js  https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js

app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};





//nodejs/lib/_http_server.js  https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_server.js

function Server(requestListener) {
  if (!(this instanceof Server)) return new Server(requestListener);
  net.Server.call(this, { allowHalfOpen: true });

  if (requestListener) {
    this.addListener('request', requestListener);
  }

  this.httpAllowHalfOpen = false;

  this.addListener('connection', connectionListener);

  this.addListener('clientError', function(err, conn) {
    conn.destroy(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const app = express();
let server = require('http').Server(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

This makes the server listening to the port we provide.

```
const app = express();
let server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.listen(3000);
```

So Server and createServer are the same according to the node.js HTTP library source code.

> Ref : [nodejs/lib/http.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/http.js)

```
exports.Server = Server;

exports.createServer = function(requestListener) {
  return new Server(requestListener);
```

};