# Socket.io port configuration with Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to get socket.io working on my heorku app, but I think I'm having some trouble defining the ports. On the backend I have my express app listening to the process.env port or 5000, and I have my socket.io port listening on 8000.

**Node.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

const socketPort = 8000;
io.listen(socketPort);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port} !`));
```

And on my front end I have my socket to route requests to localhost:8000

**Reactjs**

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000')

//Open connection to backend
socket.on('connect', ()=>{
    console.log("Connected");           
})
```

It works just fine when I run it locally, but I can't get it working on Heroku - `GET http://localhost:8000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MszLUDm net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Is there a specific way I need to set up these ports? As far as I know I can only set up one process.env port. Should I be subbing something into the "localhost:8000" on the front end?

Thanks!

Comment: Well when I worked with node.js and express I got the following line: `var http = require('http').Server(app);`, which I then could pass to `var io = require('socket.io')(http);`. Because you will need a seperate Http instance that you can pass to your socket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492101/what-is-happening-when-requirehttp-server-is-evaluated-with-an-express-app.  Maybe it helps you ;).

Comment: Thanks Tom - I actually do have that included in my original code.  Made some edits to my post for clarification. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: Well is `io.listen` necessary then? Can't remember using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side I ended up just declaring the socket like this:

```
const socket = io();
```

Leaving out the `localhost:5000` part altogether.